# Creating buffer for continuous data gathering app in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

While writing an app I stumbled upon a data management problem. Without getting into much of a detail, my app is receiving data from measurement system via Bluetooth - each sample every 20ms. On this data I have to do two things - prepare for computations (quick operation of removing bad samples) and make some advanced computations (one of them is calculating FFT). The calculated data is then displayed on a main thread.

As you can see I need to use some kind of buffer before main computations done on my data. At this is where I need advice - how would you propose to do such buffer? Right now I have done two threads - one for Bluetooth and second for computation (I know it can't be in main thread). The Bluetooth thread is sending data to main thread via handlers, so I don't know if using handlers from the computational thread is good idea - wouldn't they block each other from time to time so I will loose some data?

To better understand what I am talking about I am attaching a simple image describing my idea:
[image: idea]

Answer (score 0):

Using the first **Thread**(that is used for Bluetooth reception ) store all the messages from the BT socket into a **Queue 1**,
Write an another **thread 2** to poll the **Queue 1** ,and perform your quick operation to remove the bad samples and store the good samples in another **Queue 2** , 
Using another **Thread 3** , read the messages from the **Queue 2** and make your advanced operations.